# How do I make a react app that preserves the data on refresh

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json

I've built a simple expense tracker app on react like such

How do I now make it such that the `expenselog` object avoids reverting back to the default state on refreshing but preserves the new expenses that were added by the client

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  var [expenselog,setExpenselog] = useState([
    {
      name: "Expense1",
      amount: 1000
    },
    {
      name: "Expense2",
      amount: 100
    }
  ]);

  var [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  var [name, setName] = useState("");

  const inputChangeHandler = (e) => { 
    setName(e.target.value);
  }

  const inputChangeHandler2 = (e) => { 
    setCount(e.target.value);
  }
  
  const clickHandler = () => { 
    if (name === "" || count === "" || count <= 0) {
      alert("Please enter a name and amount");
    } else {
    setExpenselog([...expenselog, {name: name, amount: count}]);
    document.querySelector('.inputField').value = "";
    document.querySelector('.inputField2').value = 0;
    setCount(0);
    setName("");
    }
  }
  var sum=0;

  for (var i = 0; i < expenselog.length; i++) {
    sum = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(expenselog[i].amount);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={inputChangeHandler} className='inputField'/>
      <input type={"number"} onChange={inputChangeHandler2} className='inputField2'/>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Add Expense</button>
      <br/>
      <h1>Total money spent : {sum}</h1>
      {expenselog.map(expense => <p>{expense.name} - {expense.amount}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Like the previous answer mentioned, you're going to need to persist the state of your app across react's hot-reloading mounts. You can opt for a state management library, write to a local text file with the help of an external library, or utilize the browsers local storage API. I'd recommend using the local storage API with [this](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage) react hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select betweeon [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).
`localStorage` can be shared between tabs, and will persist if you close the tab.
`sessionStorage` can not be shared between tabs. When you close tab, it will disappear.